# Unable to connect SQLServer inside docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

I'm creating a container, which has an   .net core application, based on the official microsoft image.

I'm getting the following error when the application try to connect to SQL server, it only happens inside the container: **A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)**

My application uses the following packages for communcicate with sqlserver:

- System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.2
- Dapper 2.0.78

My connectionstring looks like this:

```cs
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXXX;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=60;TrustServerCertificate=true
```

My docker Version isthe latest avaliable at the time: "Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61" is running on windows and this is how i'm creating the docher image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /prj

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish myapp.csproj -o /app 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app

RUN update-ca-certificates --fresh

COPY --from=build-env /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

I've been googling for some time now, and I didn't found a solution that works for me, can some one help?

Comment: Why are you using System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.2 in a .NET Core application? You probably mean to be using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead with Dapper 2.x.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @AlwaysLearning, yes but after changing the package, the problem remains

Comment: With Net5 I have the same error 
I found this bug that seems quite related https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/633

Answer (score 2):

[This error typically occurs in client environments like docker image containers, Unix clients, or Windows clients where TLS 1.2 is the minimum supported TLS protocol.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)

Configure TLS/SSL settings in the docker image/client environment to connect with TLS 1.0.

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1 
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Comment: Anyway, same question, do we need to run `sed -i 's/TLSv1.2/TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` or we can use the ENV?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a very similar error:

> Error: **A connection was successfully established with the server**, but
> then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)

I had to add  `Encrypt=false;` item to the connection string.
I am also using the IP Address from docker settings.

After that, it worked perfectly.

```
"Server=232.13.1.2;Initial Catalog=FakeDbName;User ID=sa;Password=This1sAFak3P@ass;Encrypt=False;"
```